# Regex exclude specific subdomain (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I want to exclude a specific subdomain from a regex.
I have searched and tryed out different regex. But non worked for me.

The normal regex looks like this:

```
https?:\/\/((localhost(\:\d+)?)|([a-z\-\.]*\.)?(gaga.ch|gugus.ch))
```

To exclude a subdomain with name *admin* in gugus.ch I added:`(^(?!.*admin).*)`
So the whole regex looks like:

```
https?:\/\/((localhost(\:\d+)?)|([a-z\-\.]*\.)?(gaga.ch|(^(?!.*admin).*)gugus.ch))
```

So it should let through `http://www.gugus.ch`
But NOT `http://admin.gugus.ch`

This does not work. What I'am doing wrong?

thx Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
https?://((localhost(:\d+)?)|([a-z.-]*\.)?(gaga\.ch|(?<!\badmin\.)gugus\.ch)
```

`(?<!\badmin\.)` is a **negative lookbehind** to fail the match if `gugus.ch` is preceded by `admin.`